# Inline citation within my inline citation (MLA)

Tags: citations

I am using a source, which, across the three sentences I am citing, includes two parenthetical citations.

For example:

If this is my sentence, and now I cite: "this is my source sentence one (Other Author 1891). And, he continues with more (A different author 1912)." (My Source Author)

Must I include my sources parenthetical citations within my quotation? My inclination is no.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [MLA style detailed here](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/747/02/) you can use the following for inline citing as per the example you gave.

> **Citing indirect sources**
>
> Sometimes you may have to use an indirect source. An indirect source is a source cited in another source. For such indirect quotations, use "qtd. in" to indicate the source you actually consulted. For example:
>   Ravitch argues that high schools are pressured to act as "social service centers, and they don't do that well" (qtd. in Weisman 259).
>
> Note that, in most cases, a responsible researcher will attempt to find the original source, rather than citing an indirect source.

So from the information you gave, your cite would be (qtd. in My Source Author pagenumber)

It may also be of benefit to enquire if your department have a style-sheet that would give guidance on referencing.

Comment: So in my example, I would do something like drop his parentheticals, and then just use (qtd. in x)? I think that seems reasonable. I'll confirm with a prof if possible. Thanks for the link—I had quite a bit of trouble googling the guidelines.

Comment: @modusponens Yes that appears to be correct. I have edited my answer to provide a working example as well.